# Java TCP client/server sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on a problem that will create a TCP server and client using sockets.  For the client code, my objective is to repeatedly prompt the user to enter a sentence S, send the sentence S to the server, receive the response from the server, and display the message received and the round trip time expressed in milliseconds.  On the server, my objective is to create a TCP server socket, wait for a client to connect, receive a message, display it with the IP address and port # of the client, capitalize the message, display the message, and echo back the "capitalized" message.

I am trying to use a while (!(input.equals("done"){ ...do something }, however, whatever I do is getting stuck in an infinite loop.  I hope its something simple I am just overlooking, but I don't see it.

TCPServer.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class myFirstTCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int servPort = 4999;
        ServerSocket Sy = new ServerSocket(servPort);
        Socket servSocket = Sy.accept();

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(servSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
        String str = bf.readLine();

        while (!(str.equals("done"))){

            System.out.println("client connected");


            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String ip = address.getHostAddress();
            System.out.println("IP: " + ip);
            System.out.println("Port: " + servPort);

            System.out.println("Message from client: " + str.toUpperCase());

            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(servSocket.getOutputStream());
            pr.println(str);
            pr.flush();
        }
        servSocket.close();
    }
}
```

TCPClient.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myFirstTCPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String S;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        S = input.nextLine();
        Socket clntSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 4999);

        while (!(S.equals("done"))){
            double sent = System.nanoTime();
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(clntSocket.getOutputStream());
            pr.println(S);
            pr.flush();

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(clntSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);

            String str = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message from server: " + str);
            double received = System.nanoTime();
            double total = received - sent;
            System.out.println("Round Trip Time: " + (total/1000000.0));
        }
        clntSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: the value of `str` never changes, so maybe put `str = bf.readLine();` into your loop.  You have a similar problem with the client too.

Comment: You don't seem to be carefully thinking about what goes inside the loop versus what should be outside it in TCPServer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to move reader into the while loop. Because this is where server waits for reading clients input.

```
    public class myFirstTCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int servPort = 4999;
        ServerSocket Sy = new ServerSocket(servPort);
        Socket servSocket = Sy.accept();
        System.out.println("client connected");

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(servSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);

        String str ="";
        while (true)){

            str = bf.readLine();

            if(str.equals("done")) break;

            InetAddress address = servSocket.getInetAddress();
            String ip = address.getHostAddress();
            System.out.println("IP: " + ip);
            System.out.println("Port: " + servPort);

            System.out.println("Message from client: " + str);

            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(servSocket.getOutputStream());
            pr.println(str.toUpperCase());
            pr.flush();
        }
        servSocket.close();
    }
    }
```

---

### And then change client side:

```
public class myFirstTCPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String S="";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // you need to provide your server ip/domain
        // InetAddress.getLocalHost() , still works but only works when 
        // your client is in the same machine. 
        Socket clntSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4999);

        while (!(S.equals("done"))){
            System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
            S = input.nextLine();
            double sent = System.nanoTime();
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(clntSocket.getOutputStream());
            pr.println(S);
            pr.flush();

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(clntSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);

            String str = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message from server: " + str);
            double received = System.nanoTime();
            double total = received - sent;
            System.out.println("Round Trip Time: " + (total/1000000.0));
        }
        clntSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still wrong. If the first `str` read is `done`, it will be treated as a client message, echoed, etc. The test must be after the `readLine()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. However objective is to indicating what is wrong with this code not to cover all corner cases. Anyway I've updated the code.